# Python script to search a img in a website and download

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to write an automatic script that fetches the SKU codes from an excel file and searches for them on the website.
After searching I need to find the url of the image, download the image on the computer, the name of the image must be the same as the corresponding SKU.

I've already managed to enter the site and type the sku in the search bar, but then when I search for the image's xpath the site is blocked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
username = input("User: ")
password = getpass("Pass: ")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("http://portal.eaglebrandstrade.pt/#/")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
username_textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)
password_textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-primary")
button.click()
SKU = "lind-00024"
driver.get("http://portal.eaglebrandstrade.pt/#/skudetail")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
mysearch = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[1]")
mysearch.send_keys(SKU)
mysearch.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[1]")
img.get_attribute("srl")``
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the site is blocked"?  (what happens?)  Seems like the last line should be img.get_attribute("src")  Typo?

Comment: it keeps loading but does nothing
and the message that comes up in Python is this: - Image URL: None

Comment: Yap, I've already changed the last line that should say img.get_attribute("src"), it still gives the same error